# 3D to 2D world object coordinate transformation

Tags: c++, computer-vision, slam

I have the following (simplified) code which represents a 3D pose of a robot estimated by visual odometry:

```
// (r11 r12 r13 tx)
// (r21 r22 r23 ty)
// (r31 r32 r33 tz)
// (0   0   0   1)
Eigen::Matrix4f pose_prev_to_cur;
Eigen::Matrix4f pose_cur_to_world;

while (1) {
    pose_prev_to_cur = ... /* from visual odometry */
    pose_cur_to_world = pose_cur_to_world * pose_prev_to_cur.inverse();
}
```

As you can see, the pose matrix contains a 3x3 3D rotation matrix and a 3x1 translation vector.
I am plotting the robot trajectory by creating a point on a map for every frame:

```
// x translation maps to 2D x axis
int x = WINDOW_SCALE * pose_cur_to_world(0, 3) + WINDOW_SIZE / 2;
// z translation maps to 2D y axis
int y = WINDOW_SCALE * pose_cur_to_world(2, 3) + WINDOW_SIZE / 2;
// plotting the point
cv::circle(traj, cv::Point(x, y), 1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
```

This works well for me and the trajectory is plotted, as you can see in the image:
[image]
The trajectory is green, the current robot position is red.

Now I have depth readings for each frame too. For each image pixel obtained from the camera, I have a depth measurement in meters. I'd like to plot the distance in the map as well.
My current idea is to just 'add' the depth value to the z translation value of the pose matrix like so:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f pose_depth_reading = pose_cur_to_world;

// offset z location by depth reading in meters
pose_depth_reading(2, 3) += 2.0;
```

Now my question is: how to plot this new point in the map?
If I just plot the point using the x/z coordinates of the 3D points, it will obviously not be rotated properly, as it will just have an offset on the Y axis.

I thought about taking the calculated 2D map point and offsetting its y coordinate by the depth reading and then do 2D rotation about the origin instead. But my problem is I'd need to acquire the 2D rotation angle from the 3x3 3D rotation matrix in `pose_cur_to_world` and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

The end result I expect is shown in the following image:
[image]
The depth reading(s) are marked blue and I added a gray coordinate frame with X and Y axis for brevity.